# Can a vs code extension change the vs code settings?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I would like to know if I can make an extension that enables "Render Whitespace" to all. I know that you can change it in "File->Preferences->Settings->Render Witespace:all" but my question is that I want that when a user installs my extension this property changes.

[image]

It is posible?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your extension code may and can change any settings in the user, workspace or machine scope.

Notice there is a gear icon next to every setting, which lets you copy the setting ID:
[image: Setting ID]

Copy the ID and use it in this code:

```js
await vscode.workspace.getConfiguration()
    .update('editor.renderWhitespace', 'selection', vscode.ConfigurationTarget.Global);
```

Here is a full example of how to work with configuration settings: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/master/configuration-sample